# ImageView alignment in android

Tags: java, android, xml, imageview, alignment

I want to put two images in a horizontal row in my activity, one at the right side of screen and another one on the left side of screen.
I want to do it relatively and not by giving some specified numeric values as margin or sth. (to keep app compatible to all size of screens )
Any ideas?

Comment: you can put screenshot or something to show exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Put both ImageViews in RelativeLayout and write `android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"` for 1st ImageView and write `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"`for 2nd ImageView